# Get specific field Data backup along with Update query in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a local version of my database where I have added some **data to specific column** in my table (at local PC) and now ٰ I want to update only that specific column data into my live database table which is On a server. I tried to searched but find something like this but it is exporting only data no Update SQL query.

[image]

output:

```
PK;"TTID"
1;1211003
2;1211004
3;213020
4;413034
5;213011
6;213016
7;213013
8;213012
9;213018
10;213015
11;213014
```

is there any automatic way available to do this thing or i have to add all the manual entries myself.

Comment: The insert command will allow you to insert data from another table into a table. See the INSERT / SELECT syntax. If you are updating existing rows, there will need to be some relationship between the tables so you can match rows from the two tables.

Comment: Also, if this is an ongoing need, you can set up triggers to do this each time the column is updated/inserted.

Comment: I guess you didn't understand. I want to add some data to server in the same table.

Comment: In your question, you state: **into another database table(On server) **. please edit your question, and be more specific on what you want to do, maybe show an example.

Comment: I have added some more details, I mean that i just want to update my local data to the live database at server. The tables are same but one column should be updated

Comment: If there is a common unique key, it could be done several ways. Can you connect to both databases from either your local machine or the remote machine? If so, you could have a script generate the update statements

Answer (score 0):

If your local machine can connect to both databases, the following should work to updte on or more columns on the "live" server from the "local" server.

Just substitute the real server names, dbnames and column names.

If you want to update columns on the local machine from the live server, just reverse the liveserver and localserver values.

```
UPDATE liveserver.dbname.tablename
JOIN localserver.dbname.tablename
ON liveserver.dbname.tablename.keycolname = localserver.dbname.tablename.keycolname
SET liveserver.dbname.tablename.targetcolname = localserver.dbname.tablename.sourcecolname
```